# The most effective way to use design data

Tags: mvvm-light

First way, that i always used before, is to define design data in xaml:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignDataSource=/DesignData/MainPivot/ProductCategoriesDesignData.xaml}"
```

However, after starting using mvvm light, i found out its own way. via ViewModelLocator:

```
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            // Create design time view services and models
        }
        else
        {
            // Create run time view services and models
        }
```

So which one is preferable? (not sure if second way is accessible from Blend, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the nicest features in MVVM Light is how it handles design-time data.

Here's why I really like using design-time services rather than

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignDataSource=/DesignData/MainPivot/ProductCategoriesDesignData.xaml}"
```

1. You'll write less design-time code.  You'll almost always have more viewmodels than services.
2. Your viewmodels get used properly with their logic being tested properly.  They make calls to the mock services and process the data as they would normally.
3. The mock services may actually point out bugs in your viewmodels.
4. All the design-time code gets removed from the Xaml.  It's cleaner

Comment: Sounds promising. I also prefer to have more C# code than XAML.

Comment: http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007091401.html
quite nice article, hope it can be usefull